# How to convert foreign characters in regex search to proper case?

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-replace-callback

I have written the function below. It converts lower caser to upper case and proper case. I want it to ignore foreign characters. eg. ñ

**Expected result:** Sabiña/Cerca

**Actual Result:** SabiÑA/Cerca

**NOTE:** if I use mb_convert_case alone it does not change any character after/ to proper case.

```
$string= 'SABIÑA CERCA';

echo  preg_replace_callback('/\w+/i', 

create_function('$m','

var_dump($m);
if(strlen($m[0]) > 3)
{
    return mb_convert_case($m[0], MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
}
else
{
    return ucfirst($m[0]);
}')
, $string);
```

Comment: As an aside, using `create_function('$m', '` is a bit old school since now you can write `function ($m) {...}`. Other thing, since you are dealing with multibyte strings you need to use `mb_strlen` to obtain the number of characters (and not the number of bytes that returns `strlen`). To finish, even with the corrected pattern, your code will not work with a word that starts with an accented letter. To solve the problem, see the different suggestions to emulate `mb_ucfirst` in the php manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the `/u` modifier.

```
'/\w+/u'
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/8Z56XA)

Note that the `/i` case insensitive modifier is redundant because **`\w` matches both lower- and uppercase letters**.

See [Pattern modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32.